# Creating a Social Networking Web Service API

Tags: web-services, api, asmx, social-networking

I need help writing an API for a social networking site. My main question is how did Facebook not use SSL and write an API?  If they didn't use an API, the user information is all passed in clear text, which is extremely unsafe, so how did they pass the password in the API?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, most social networking sites (Facebook, Twitter, etc) use OAuth to authenticate third-party consumers.

Basically, a service provider (Facebook) enters a conditional agreement with a consumer (like Farmville). When a user (you) wants to use Farmville, the consumer will pass on your request to the service provider, and you have the option of allowing or denying the consumer from accessing your protected resources on the provider (eg: Facebook prompts you and asks, "Do you want to allow Farmville to access your friends list, photos, etc.?"). Once you authorize the consumer to access your protected resources, the consumer has access to your protected resources until the token is removed (it can expire or be removed manually).

This has the advantage of never giving a third-party (like Farmville) credentials for your protected resource (Facebook account), (aka: password anti-pattern).

You should implement OAuth provider services for your social networking site. You can look through [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) and [Facebook's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) authentication documentation as well as the www.oauth.net to get an idea of how OAuth is implemented.

Comment: Thanks! I had heard of oAuth before, but wasn't aware of its true potential. I'll look into it now.